# Delphi 2007 and Indy10 compile error in IdStackWindows

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-2007, indy10

I've just updated my Indy10 installation to the latest revision (5276) and I now get an error when trying to compile a Windows application.

> IdStackWindows.pas(2364) Error: E2029 '..' expected but ';' found

The issue seems to be the declaration of `ka: tcp_keepalive` on line 2364 in `TIdStackWindows.SetKeepAliveValues`.

I'm using Delphi 2007 on Windows 7 Professional x64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further investigation I found that there is a new `TCP_KEEPALIVE` constant being declared in IdWinsock2.pas:

```
  {$EXTERNALSYM TCP_KEEPALIVE}
  TCP_KEEPALIVE         = 3;
```

This conflicts with the existing `tcp_keepalive` record, so that has been renamed to `_tcp_keepalive`.  Updating the `ka` variable declared in `TIdStackWindows.SetKeepAliveValues()` to this new typename resolves the error.

I then found another compile issue in IdSSLOpenSSL.pas:

> [DCC Error] IdSSLOpenSSL.pas(980): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or
>   external declaration: 'IndySSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file'

This error can be resolved by adding a missing implementation of `IndySSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file()` inside the `{$ELSE}` section of an `{$IFDEF STRING_IS_UNICODE}` block that starts at line 1155, and have it simply call OpenSSL's standard `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file()` function.

**UPDATE:**
All the necessary fixes (described above) are available in revision 5277 and later.

Comment: Now, let also Remy about this fix.

Comment: I'm sure Remy Lebeau will see this question, review the changes and commit a fix soon.

Comment: I have checked in my fixes. SteB's proposed fix for the OpenSSL error was not the correct solution, though.  I have implemented the correct one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I see what you've done, could you edit my answer to include your changes and why they're necessary?

Comment: Rather than edit the answer to describe the changes, it seems better to edit the answer to say simply, "There were some conflicting definitions; make sure you update to at least checkin *xyz* to receive the fixes." We don't need to encourage everyone to change their local copies of the code when the changes are already available globally.